# Insert data into RedShift by using Pyhon

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Can data be inserted into a RedShift from a local computer without copying data to S3 first? 
Basically as a direct insert of record by record into RedShift?

If yes - what library / connection string can be used?
(I am not concerned about performance)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried... inserting it?

Comment: No, no access, asking for a friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can data be inserted into a RedShift from a local computer without copying data to S3 first? Basically as a direct insert of record by record into RedShift?

Yes, it could be done. But not a preferred method, though you have already weighted, that performance is not a concern.

You could use`psycopg2` liberary. You could run this from any machine(local/on EC2 or any other cloud platform) having network connection to/for allowed to/from to your Redshift instance.
Here is python code snippet.

```
import psycopg2


def redshift():

    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='your_database', host='a********8.****s.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', user='user', password='Pass')

    cur = conn.cursor();

    cur.execute('insert into test values('1','2','3','4')")

    print('success ')


redshift();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you talk about RedShift or RedShift Spectrum.

In RSS you have to put the data on S3 but if you use RedShift you can make an insert with sqlalchemy for example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to query AWS Redshift from python is through this Jupyter extension - [Jupyter Redshift](https://github.com/sat28/jupyter-redshift)

Not only can you query and save your results but also **write them back** to the database from within the notebook environment.